# What are some Applications of the Permanent of a Matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I have a decent understanding of the determinant of a matrix in terms of its role in

- Telling you if a matrix is invertible (zero vs. nonzero)
- Expressing the product of a matrix's eigenvalues with multiplicities
- Representing the constant term in a matrix's characteristic polynomial
- Having geometrical interpretations

However, I was curious to learn in the operation known as the [permanent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent) has any interesting properties. The permanent is defined in the same way a determinant is, but all entries are added instead of alternating between positive and negative terms.

In particular, **what are the significant applications of defining the permanent as a notable matrix operation?** Also, are there any matrix problems whose solutions directly/indirectly depend on understanding the permanent?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/761297/why-is-the-permanent-of-interest-for-complexity-theorists

Comment: @studiosus I like the information in your link from a theoretical standpoint, but it doesn't quite answer the question. I'm looking for a more application-oriented answer or problem that can be solved using permanents, not necessarily knowing about the time complexity to compute them.

Comment: Well, if you _really understand_ permanents, you will prove that P equals NP or, vice versa, that P is not equal to NP; this will have major ramifications in the computer science and will earn you $10^6$ USD among other things. I guess, however, this is not an answer you are looking for, therefore I posted this link just as a comment. (+1 for the question itself.)

Answer (score 3):

Finding Permanent of square matrix is equivalent to finding:

(1) Number of perfect matching in the Bipartite graph (Biadjacencey Matrix).

(2) Number of cycle cover in the Directed graph (adjacency matrix).

[You can check on Wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permanent)

(3) Number of monomial in Read-twice  Formula [Check this paper](http://www.imsc.res.in/~meena/papers/monomials-mfcs12.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

To complement a previous answer, permanents are common in physics: by the spin-statistics theorem, the many-particle states of identical bosons must be fully symmetric under permutation, and an easy way to construct such fully symmetric states is to use permanents, where the entry $(ij)$ is $\phi_i(x_j)$, describing particle $j$ in state $i$.  This works because the permanent is unchanged if one permutes any two rows or columns of a matrix.  The many-body state is thus a polynomial in the single particle states.  (Conversely the many particle states of identical fermions must be antisymmetric and one uses determinants for those (see [this wiki page on Slater determinants](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slater_determinant).)

Possibly the most spectacular recent application of permanents (and associated computational complexity) is the [BosonSampling problem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boson_sampling), where it is shown that the distribution of permanents resulting from the interference of indistinguishable photons (they are bosons) is #P-hard (exactly or approximately).